# Ordering and synchronization of CoreData NSNotification

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsnotifications

Maybe this is a too simple question, but one thing I have learnt from other developers about objective-c programming is that custom NSNotifications have not predicted order.

So, what's the mechanism behind CoreData notification, that made possible NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification and the rest are delivered in a specific order ?

How is that possible that listening class do not get notification overlapped or in a wrong order ?

Comment: Which specific notifications are you worried about?

Comment: All the three of them, from will save to did change, I am wondering how can they be sent and received in a given order.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty certain that the order is just the obvious one when you change something and save:

```
1. NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification
2. NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification
3. NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
```

You can easily check that with log statements. In my experience, this order was 100% reliable.

However, you are correct in pointing out that the lose relationship through notifications cannot really guarantee delivery, let alone at a specified time. If you want to be certain that you receive certain callbacks, you should use a `NSFetchedResultsController` delegate. This much closer relationship will all but ensure your changes can be reacted to in a determined order.

Comment: Thanks, the point is that I know that they come in correct order, and it's always like that (and as you said 100% reliable). I am trying to investigate the reason behind that.

Comment: The reason is that they are sent in this order by the framework. There is no plausible scenario why they should change order.